# how to prove that the following function is primitive recursive?

Tags: logic

I have the following question:

let $f(\vec{x})$ be an everywhere defined function, constructed from the primitive recursive function $g(\vec{x},y)$ using the $\mu-$ operator. that is:

$f(\vec{x})=(\mu y(g(\vec{x},y)=0)$

then there is a primitive recursive function $h$ such that its range is the range of $f$

my solution:

let's define

$h(\vec{x},z)=(\mu y(g(\vec{x},y)=0)$

knowing that $g(\vec{x},y)$ is primitive recursive and that $\mu$ operator does not influence the primitive recursiveness we have that $h(\vec{x},z)$ is primitive recursive.  also $f(\vec{x})=h(\vec{x},z)$ by construction so the range of the two functions is the same set as well.

Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the above proof? thank you

Comment: The $\mu$ operator is not primitive recursive.

Comment: It's generally better to improve the existing question than [delete and re-ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3041929/how-to-prove-that-hx-%E2%83%97-z-%CE%BCygx-%E2%83%97-y-0-is-primitive-recursive).

Answer (score 1):

> $\mu$ operator does not influence the primitive recursiveness

This is **false**: throwing in $\mu$ ruins primitive recursiveness in general. Even if $g(x,y)$ is primitive recursive, and for every $x$ there is some $y$ with $g(x,y)=0$, the function $x\mapsto \mu y[g(x,y)=0]$ need not be primitive recursive.

The reason is that searching for the desired $y$ is "too unbounded" to be primitive recursive. You're going to need to find an "impatient" way to produce the relevant range. This is where the additional variable is going to come in - think about what happens if we fix a bound on the length of our search ahead of time, but allow that bound to vary (that is, *represent it by a new variable* which our function can take as input) ...

---

Incidentally, one point which should give you pause is the fact that your "solution" $h$ *doesn't actually use the new variable $z$.* So, what's the point of having it?